# Explain the syntax for function declaration

Tags: go, syntax

Please explain the below syntax, I found this below snippet from godoc. I understand `Cookie` is function name and `name` is its argument and return type are `(*Cookie, error)`, the part I could not understand is `(r *Request)`, What exactly this part signifies. By the way I am from OOP background.

```
func (r *Request) Cookie(name string) (*Cookie, error)
```

Comment: https://golang.org/ref/spec#Method_declarations

Comment: I don't understand the reason people downvote question, Is it not allowed to ask question on this platform? I am new to this, and could not find any help. So asked on SO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is called a receiver.

Basically if a function has something before it's name (the receiver) it is now called a method. It's a good way to take structs as arguments.

I would recommend going over https://tour.golang.org/methods/1 for more information.

https://gobyexample.com/methods is also sweet